# How can I Print a number of Dropdowns Determined by User while Inside Every Dropdown Selected Options Remain Selected after POST, with PHP?

Tags: php, forms, for-loop, drop-down-menu, ternary-operator

The problem I'm facing is quite complex, at least for me as I am new to PHP. But I'm sure there's a much simpler way to solve it than I might think.

Also, I am deeply sorry for any messy code, but please do suggest cleaner ways because I care about order!

Here's how I imagined it:
The user first selects a number of dropdowns and later, for every new dropdown, they have to select an option.
E.g. user selects 5, it gives them 5 dropdowns, into each they then have to put a value.

Here's the first bit, the one where they select the number of dropdowns:

```
<select type="option" name="formDropdownNum" />
<option value="0">Please select</option>
<?php
for ($i=1; $i <= 15; $i++) { // Printing 15 dropdowns
    // If option was selected, marking it as selected for future
    print('<option value="' . $i . '"' . (($_POST['formDropdownNum'] == $i) ? 'selected="selected"' : "") . '>' . $i . ' Dropdown');
    // Adding 's' for plural form if >1 dropdown
    if ($i>1) {
        print('s');
    }
    print('</option>');
}

// Storing user selection into session
if (isset($_POST['formDropdownNum'])) {
    $_SESSION['selectedDropdownNum'] = intval($_POST['formDropdownNum']);
}
else {
    $_SESSION['selectedDropdownNum'] = 0;
}
?>
</select>
```

The problem arises when I want these *new* dropdowns to have their options selected after POST, since they're created by a `print();` function. I know how to do this in general using the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), but really what's troubling me is this:

```
<?php
// Printing as many dropdowns as specified by user
for ($n=1; $n <= $_SESSION['selectedDropdownNum']; $n++) {
print('<select type="option" name="formDropdown' . $n . '">'); // naming each dropdown with a different name (to be able to store chosen values from each of them later)
for ($m=1; $m <= 15; $m++) {
    // Printing all possible options to choose from inside each new dropdown
    // Leaving selected values selected after POST
    // Using ternary operator to determine which option in which dropdown was selected
    print('<option value="' . $m . '"' . (($_POST['formDropdown' . $n] == 'formModule' . $m) ? 'selected="selected"' : "") . '>' .  . 'Option' . ' $m');
    print('</option>');
}
print('</select>');
```

}

Since these newly generated options would not have static `name="name"` attributes but would be printed inside of a for loop (depending on the user's selection made earlier) and be named '*formDropdown1*', '*formDropdown2*', etc., depending on how many the user wants - the `$_POST['formDropdown#']` inside the ternary cannot a constant value.

And I know that this is not done correctly, but I put the `. $n` into the `$_POST[]` anyway for you to see what I wanted to achieve.

```
print('<option value="' . $m . '"' . (($_POST['formDropdown' . $n] == 'formModule' . $m) ? 'selected="selected"' : "") . '>' .  . 'Option' . ' $m');
```

Many thanks for your effort to help a learner!

Cheers,

Ciy

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but I don't see anything wrong with the approach you've taken.

Comment: It must be something else I'm doing wrong then. i thought I was breaking the code by using a period inside a ternary.. I'll try this again.
Edit: would there be a simpler way to get through all this? It feels like I'm overcomplicating.